# Find and prove the limit of the following

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, lebesgue-measure, fubini-tonelli-theorems

> Let the triangular area $∆$ = {${(x, y) ∈ \mathbb{R}^2 | x > 0, y > 0,
> > x + y < 3}$} and the sequence $(c_n)$, ${n∈\mathbb{N}}$, with $c_n =
> > \int_{∆}(xy(3 - x - y))^n λ_2(dxdy)$ be given.
>
> The notation $λ_2(dx dy)$ means that over $( x, y)$ is integrated with
> respect to the two-dimensional Lebesgue measure $λ_2$.
>
> Find numbers $a ∈ \mathbb{R}$ and $b > 0$ such that $d_n = n^ab^nc_n$
> that defines the sequence $(d_n)_{n∈\mathbb{N}}$ so it converges to a
> positive real number $l ∈ \mathbb{R}^+$ for  $n → ∞$. Find the limit
> $l$ explicitly.

My work:

As of now I think that I should transform the integral with an affine-linear transformation with suitable $α ∈ \mathbb{R}$ such as $x˜ = n^α(x − 1)$, $y˜ = n^α(y − 1)$ and to study the asymptotics $n → ∞$ of the integrand after the transformation, but I haven't gotten anywhere with it.

I have also thought to use the Fubini Theorem to compute the integral, and then deal with the inner and outer integrals, so as to find the limit of $c_n$. As per my calculations the inner integral should be a Beta-Integral, but I'm not sure of my computations and how to proceed. Could you guys help?

Comment: Why did you erase the question about the convergence of an integral? By waiting a bit more, you could have gotten an answer.

Comment: @coudy it had no replies after 5 hours and not gaining views anymore so I thought nobody was interested. I also saw it had been copied here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4384575/how-to-prove-that-the-function-is-integrable-with-respect-to-lebesgue-measure.

Comment: Sometimes it may take a few days before someone find the solution. Also, note that you can put a bounty on your question by spending reputation points. Then the question will appear on the "bountied" page and may gain more attention. I think you lose the points awarded by a question if you delete it. I also think that if  you undelete the question, the points will be back.

Comment: @coudy thank you. I have undeleted the question. I don't have enough reputation for a bounty though.

Comment: I think you have now enough reputation. It requires 75 rep to put bounties on questions and you should be around 100. Maybe you can undelete other questions to get back reputation points.

Comment: It says that the question will be eligible for bounty in two days. Maybe I'll put a bounty on it then.